# Print all Lua reserved keywords

Tags: lua, keyword, reserved

With this code:

```
for n in pairs(_G) do print(n) end
```

I print the names of all global variables defined in the current environment.

Is there any way to print all Lua keywords (`and`,`break`,`do`,`else`,`elseif`,`end`,`false`,`for`,`function`,`if`,`in`,`local`,`nil`,`not`,`or`,`repeat`,`return`,`then`,`true`,`until`,`while`)?

Comment: The answer is no, write a table yourself.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @lhf: only a didactic one, but I will tell them which variable names to avoid, without using the shell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as reserved keywords don't correspond to any objects in memory - they only exists in parser. See manual for each version for full list, typicaly under "Lexical Conventions". For example for Lua 5.1 it is located at http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.1